# SMS sending in Python 2.6 through a data cable connection

Tags: python, sms, serial-port

I am working in Python 2.6 and I want to send SMS to a mobile while my cell phone i.e. Nokia E-72 is connected to PC via Data Cable.

The mobile is connected through a serial port and the code prompts the correct port as well and there is no error in the code but still the message is not being sent.

My code is as follows:

```
import serial
import time
phone = serial.Serial()
phone.baudrate = 38400
phone.bytesize = 8
phone.stopbits = 1
phone.xonxoff = 0
phone.rtscts = 0
phone.timeout = 0
phone.port = 4 #try different ports here, if this doesn't work.
phone.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
phone.open()
print phone.portstr
recipient = "+923219409998"
message = "We did it!"
try:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + recipient.encode() + b'"\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(message.encode() + b"\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(bytes([26]))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.readall()
finally:
    phone.close()
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting before anyone can help you to find the issue.

Comment: Not sure if the phone even permit it, and btw are you sure it's a serial connection?

Comment: yes its a serial connection. can you tell me why are you asking this?

Comment: What does `phone.write(bytes([26]))` do and why? Besides, are you sure that your `\r` is correct?

Comment: phone.write(bytes([26])) writes the message on the serial port and yes \r is part of the AT command which sets the message in the format of the mobile SMS.

Comment: If you are using a Windows machine, download and run [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) and see what goes over your serial link. It may be that the data isn't getting out, or it may be the AT commands are malformed in some why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give the connection parameters as arguments to `Serial()` instead of adding them later? Normally, a connection is opened immediately, and I am not sure if a late `open()` is effective at all...

So

1. Try something like

   ```
   phone = serial.Serial(
       baudrate=38400,
       bytesize=8,
       stopbits=1,
       xonxoff=0,
       rtscts=0,
       timeout=0,
       port=4, #try different ports here, if this doesn't work.
       parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
   )
   print phone.portstr
   ```

   otherwise the connection will be establishend with default parameters, which is probably not what you want.

   If it still doesn't work,
2. try to change the port number with the real port device string (`"COM5"`, `"/dev/ttyS5"`) and maybe
3. even parse the answer of the phone. In order to do this, you should define a timeout in the connection parameters and/or restrict your reading to the number of bytes returned by `phone.inWaiting()`.

---

Besides (but that's just a matter of style), depending on which version of Python you use, it might be neater to use

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(phone):
    <do stuff with phone>
```

instead of

```
try:
    <do stuff with phone>
finally:
    phone.close()
```

It is semantically absolutely the same, but looks better (IMHO).

Comment: @user1325702 After which of the numbered steps it doesn't work? What do the others result in?

Comment: the program gives no error and it displays the port number on which mobile is connected (which is Correct). and the phone closes in the end but it does not send the sms.

Comment: Fine. So check the other issues I pointed out (parsing or at least displaying of phone's answer and check that your line endings are correct, as I already wrote.)

Comment: we tried the parsing of phone response by reading from the serial port and joining all the characters in a buffer but nothing came on the console.. perhaps because nothing is comping from the mobile phone as a response.